# How to write down a probabilistic function in Wolfram Language?

Tags: function-construction, probability-or-statistics

How does one write a Wolfram function which has a 25% chance of returning 1, a 50% chance of returning 2, and a 25% chance of returning 3?

Here is how the data structure might look like:

```
D = {(0.25, 1), (0.5, 2), (0.25, 3)}
```

So how do we write an

```
f[D_] := ...
```

with the property above? (Or if this is not the best/most idiomatic data structure for this type of problem, then feel free to dismiss it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a one-off call:

```
RandomChoice[{0.25, 0.5, 0.25} -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

To make a function as you request:

```
f[d_] := RandomChoice[d[[All, 1]] -> d[[All, 2]]]
f[{{0.25, 1}, {0.5, 2}, {0.25, 3}}]
```

Note a couple things: 1) `D` is a reserved keyword (for derivative).  In general, avoid using capitalized variables.  2) A list needs to be created with braces `{}`, not parentheses `()`.